# How to align & center images in a row using css?

Tags: html, css

I have this code that I've written to place an image of an icon in the bottom of a dropdown menu:

```css
.menu li:last-child img {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li class="last"><img src="facebooktransparent.png"><img src="facebooktransparent.png"><img src="facebooktransparent.png"><img src="facebooktransparent.png"></li>
</ul>
```

How to center a total of 4 icons in a row? All four together should then be centered.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a minimal example of what you're trying to debug. Please read [how to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I think you're looking for [CSS Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout), and in particular `justify-content: center` to horizontally center content on the X axis.

Comment: Thanks @TannerDolby I wanted to know if I had 4 icons to be displayed in a horizontal row, then I'd just place <img> tags with this justify-content css?

Comment: Great, have a look at creating a parent flex container and nesting <img> elements as flex items to then be centered! Next time, try adding that part about "trying something" to the question as its easier for us to help you. Goodluck!

Comment: @sd100 nobody needs to "approve" your post. You ask for solutions, yet you didn't even provide enough code to show what you want. You are asking about four images, yet, I only see one and since it's a relative path to the image, it would result in the image not found for us. Post the exact code you are having trouble with.

Comment: please, update your code - dropdown menu and 4 images in a row? In your code menu has one image as the only element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try flex box. It works magic when you want to center in row or column.

```css
.menu{
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    }

.menu .last{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        }

.last img{
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
    }
```

Comment: Subreena, your snippet would be much better with a bit of HTML to make it work.

Comment: Also, using `display: flex` by default includes `flex-direction: row` so it is redundant to include here.

Comment: @subreena I wanted to ask if I need to push the images towards the bottom can you update me please? Thanks!

Comment: If you wanted to push the images toward the bottom then you can change the property of align-tems to flex-end; that should should work